# Kendo daterangepicker from single input field

Tags: kendo-ui

How to bring kendo daterangepicker with a single field? there should not be 2 input fields like start and end date. once the ranges are selectedinput field should get the dates like 01-01-2019 - 20-09-2019[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbtor.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use concatenation between start date and end date of DateTimePicker like

```
    <script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')); // assign this to your textbox
  });
});
</script>
```